# Reformatting text using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a input like where first row is the header, is it possible to reformat the text as the output below?

```
awk '{if ($2=="b" || $3 == "c" || $4 == "d" || $5 == "e" || $6 == "f" || $7 == "g" || $8 == "9" )'}'
```

I tried above not working, I am a new beginner in Linux, any idea would be appreciated.

input :

```
Name    Date          Time          Mxam     Mxterm
Maxus   Date:su,mo    Time:12,3:00  mxam:20  Mxterm:10
Feros   Time:12,3:00  Mxterm:19
Michel  Mxterm:16
```

Desired output

```
Name    Date           Time              Mxam     Mxterm
Maxus   Date:su,mo     Time:12,3:00      mxam:20  Mxterm:10
Feros                  Time:12,3:00               Mxterm:19
Michel                                            Mxterm:16
```

Comment: Is that the actual data? Do you really just have single letters in alphabetical order? If not, how can we know what change to make?

Comment: Actual data is vary, but i have header name in every row,so based on that i am reformating..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add something we can use to test. How can I know that something needs to go into a different field? If I see `a e h`, how can I know that needs to be changed? We can't help you format data if you don't show us the data.

Comment: @terdon edited...

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting there, but I don't think I got it right. Please review and make sure it looks correct. I think I understand what you need now though.

Comment: Even i am not able  align in mobile.will correct by tomo..thanks

Comment: I fixed the alignments. However, why do you have `Mxam` in the header and `mxam` in the data? Is that correct?

Comment: Header names will be in all cell,Excluding the  first column.Data will be like this headername:inputdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU AWK:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
FNR==1  {n = split($0, col)}
        {printf("%s ", $1); k=2
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
                printf("%s ", $0 ~ "\\<"col[i]"\\>"?$(k++):"")
        print ""}
' file | column -ts' '
```

`IGNORECASE=1` - *Ignore case in patterns*
`column -ts' '` - *input delimiter is one space character, this greatly simplifies the program in awk.*

GNU SED:

```
sed -r '
s/\s+/ /g
1{h;b};G
:1;s/( \S*)(:\S*)(.*)\1/\3\1\2/i;t1
s/\n\S*//
:2;s/ [^: ]+( |$)/ \1/;t2
' file | column -ts' '
```

*A first header line is added to each line, separated by the `\n` separator. Columns on the left side except for the first one replaces the corresponding column on the right side. The remaining columns that are not have the `:` sign are replaced with a space.*

Advice for debugging sed scripts:
*Add the `-n` flag `sed -nr` and put the `l` command at the end of 3 line - `1{h;b};G;l`. Run the script, then repeat all for 4 line and so on. `l` command - show the contents of the buffer(pattern space) with an anchor end of the buffer `$`*

[awk updated]:

```
awk '
NR==1   {n = split($0, col)}
        {k=1; for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
                printf( "%s ", $0 ~ "\\<"col[i]?$(k++):"")
        print ""}
' file | column -ts' '
```

*Will work on initial headings match, but it's better to write full headings (e.g. `insert_job days_somthing start_somting window term max_run_alarm must_somthing`) and use an end-of-word anchor `"\\<"col[i]"\\>"`*

If the first column is never empty and a unique name is used as an identifier, then you can leave it as it is:

```
awk '
NR==1   {n = split($0, col)}
        {printf("%s ", $1); k=2
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
                printf("%s ", $0 ~ "\\<"col[i]?$(k++):"")
        print ""}
' file | column -ts' '
```

`col[]` - array with column names;`col[1] == "Name"`; `col[2] == "Date"`; `col[3] == "Time"` and so on. `"\\<"` - word start anchor. Example - `"\\<"col[2]` equal `"\\<Date"`

Ternary operator - `condition expression ? statement1 : statement2`
*When the condition expression returns true, statement1 gets executed; otherwise statement2 is executed.*

`$0 ~ "\\<"col[i]?$(k++):""` - Hence, if the current line `$0` contains `"\\<"col[2]`, then the next field `$(k++)` is printed in the order in which it appears on the current line (e.g. `$2` in `$0`), if not, then the empty field `""`.

[awk updated2]: Remove the trailing space.

```
awk '
NR==1   {n = split($0, col)}
        {printf("%s ", $1); k=2
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
            printf("%s%c", ($0~"\\<"col[i]?$(k++):""), (n>i?OFS:ORS))}
' file | column -ts' '
```

[awk update3]: For rearranging fields.

```
awk '
NR==1   {n = split($0, col)}
        {k=1; for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
                A[i] = ($0~"\\<"col[i]?$(k++):"")
        for(i in A) $i = A[i]
        }
1' file | column -ts' '
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: It works for me with `column -tn`.

Comment: I mean, with a pretty output.

Comment: @nezabudka oh, I have the BSD version, it's odd since I have Ubuntu ️.

Comment: is that possible to rearrange a column to last in thw awk script itself,for example 6th column to end.i tried to move the column after the final result and alignments are collapsed.awk '{$(NF+1)=$6; $6=""; $0=$0; $1=$1}1'

Comment: @Vsanya, `echo one two three four five | column -ts' ' -H 3 -O 2,4,5,1` Output: `two  four  five  one` or read update3

Comment: -H option not working for me,i moved the specific row to last while generating the input file itself by sed….thanks for everything ,can you share the manual for awk…

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your data contains tag=value pairs as you do (e.g. in `Date:su,mo` the tag is `Data` and value is `su,mo`), it's best to first construct an array to hold that mapping (`tag2val[]` below) and then you can access/print/compare the values just by their tags (aka names) in any order you like. In this case we're just printing the values by the order the tags appear in the first input row but with this approach we could easily do so much more:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==1 {
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        val = $fldNr
        tag = tolower(val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
        tags[++numTags] = tag
    }
}
NR > 1 {
    tag2val[tags[1]] = $1
    for (fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        val = $fldNr
        tag = tolower(val)
        sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }
}
{
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
Name    Date        Time          Mxam     Mxterm
Maxus   Date:su,mo  Time:12,3:00  mxam:20  Mxterm:10
Feros               Time:12,3:00           Mxterm:19
Michel                                     Mxterm:16
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `sed` solution, using `#` to visualize the spaces:

```bsh
$ sed -E '1s/\s+/#/' file | \
  tr -s ' ' '#' | \
  sed -E '2,$s/#*(D[^#]*)*#*(T[^#]*)*#*(mx[^#]*)*#*(Mx[^#]*)*$/#\1#\2#\3#\4/' | \
  tr '#' ' ' |\
  column -nt
Name    Date        Time          Mxam     Mxterm
Maxus   Date:su,mo  Time:12,3:00  mxam:20  Mxterm:10
Feros               Time:12,3:00           Mxterm:19
Michel                                     Mxterm:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to refornat your data.

We use awk to generate code for the utility `tbl` which then  pipes to `groff` text processor to tabulate our data.

```
< file \
awk -v OFS='@' '
{ split($0, a) }
NR==1{
  for (idx in a) b[tolower(a[idx])]=idx
  print ".TS"; print "tab(", ");"
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    printf "%s%s", "l", (i<NF ? OFS : ".")
  $1 = ORS $1
}
NR>1{
  $0=""; $1=a[1]
  for (i=2; i in a; i++) $(b[tolower(substr(a[i],1,-1+index(a[i],":")))]) = a[i]
}1
END { print ".TE" }
' | tbl | groff -Tascii | grep .
```

Output:

```
Name     Date         Time           Mxam      Mxterm
Maxus    Date:su,mo   Time:12,3:00   mxam:20   Mxterm:10
Feros                 Time:12,3:00             Mxterm:19
Michel                                         Mxterm:16
```